# Efficient way to store frequently requested key-value data with relations?

Tags: database, database-design, redis, bigdata, key-value

Let's say I'm building Twitter.

One of the tasks is to track, which tweets are read by particular user and store this data on server. When user requests somebody's feed, server should return:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    tweet: "Hey there!",
    isRead: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tweet: "Here's my cat, look",
    isRead: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tweet: "Blue or yellow? Thats the question",
    isRead: true
  },
  ...
]
```

Which is the most efficient way to store data for which tweets are read by which user, and retrieving this data when returning *somebody's* feed for particular user?

Any ideas about data storing architecture are highly appreciated. My current stack is PostgreSQL for storing users and "tweets". Redis, MongoDB and neo4j are also used in the project, so available.

The first guess was to use Redis, like:

```
user_id: tweet_id
-----------------
user_id: tweet_id
-----------------
....
```

But I think, there may be better variants, more suitable for persistent data storage.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Twitter-clone that Redis' author, antirez (a.k.a Salvatore Sanfilippo), had made: http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone